# Listen for specific value change on a model's attribute

Tags: events, backbone.js

I'd like to trigger a method when one of my model's attributes is changed to a specific value. How can I do that?

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        name: 'John',
        age: 34
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.on('change:age>100', this.die, this); // Here listen for specific value change
    },

    die: function(){
        alert('He had a good run');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build-in Backbone function to do it. But you can simple do it yourself. Here is simple solution:

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        name: 'John',
        age: 34
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.on('change:age', this.onChangeAge, this); // Here listen for specific value change
    },

    onChangeAge: function(model, newAge){
      if(newAge > 100){
        this.die();
      }
    },

    die: function(){
        alert('He had a good run');
    }
});
```

Or a little bit more complex:

```
var onGreaterThan = function(value, func){
  return function(model, newValue){
    if (newValue > value){
      func.apply(this, arguments);
    }    
  };
};

var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        name: 'John',
        age: 34
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.on('change:age', onGreaterThan(100, this.die), this); // Here listen for specific value change
    },

    die: function(){
        alert('He had a good run');
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought of something similar but felt checking the new value each time was a waste of resources. Was wondering if Backbone could take care on its own. Thanks for your answer!